# неправильная кодировка php mail()

Tags: php, email

Как перекодировать отправляемые сообщения в благословенный UTF-8?
Обработчик формы присылает на почту сообщения вида Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð±Ð¸Ñ€ÐºÐ° что как будто бы является кодировкой CP1252. Пробовал решить проблему с помощью функции iconv, но в результате получаю лишь пустые письма вообще без содержимого.

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");?>
<?php
       $text="";
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$val) {
        $text=$text."  ".$key.":".$val."  ";
        }
        //$text = iconv('utf-8', 'CP1252', $text);
        $title = "sendform" ;
        $to = 'xxx@yandex.ru';  
        $from='noreply@gyroshop'; 
        if(mail($to, $title, $text, 'From:'.$from))
         include("send.html"); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в неправильном написании четвёртого значения функции `mail()`

Правильно было написать:

```
echo mail($to, $title, $text,$headers);
```

Answer (score 3):

Кодировку необходимо указывать в заголовках письма, точно так же, как это делается в HTTP. В вашем случае нужно изменить четвертый параметр функции. И там прописать Content-Type:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8";
$text="";
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
    $text .= "$key:$val\n";
}
$title = "sendform" ;
$to = 'xxx@yandex.ru';  
mail($to, $title, $text, $headers);
```

Comment: Не помогает. Всё равно приходят кракозябры. Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚ Ð±Ñ€Ð¾Ð´ÑÐ³Ð°

Comment: Варианты решения типа `$text= mb_convert_encoding($p,mb_detect_encoding($p , "CP1252"), 'UTF8');
  $text= mb_convert_encoding($p,'UTF8', "CP1251");` тоже не работают - приходит вообще строка

Comment: Ваш ответ помог мыслить в правильном направлении.